# What is the differences between GoogleSignInApi.signOut and FirebaseAuth.signOut and more

Tags: android, logout, google-signin

What is the the more detail workflow difference between

```
GoogleSignInApi.signOut 

FirebaseAuth.signOut() 

GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess.
```

Going trough many tutorials and codelabs like [Build an Android App](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible#creating-project) and  [Authenticate Using Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) and [FireBase Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0)

Everything is really transparent except the behind then scene working for the above `signOut` and `revokeAccess`.

Why is `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` still holding on to the user after `GoogleSignInApi.signOut`has runned. Does this mean I must keep track of the state in some e.g. `SharedPreferences`. When I call the `FirebaseAuth.signOut()`the user is indeed removed from `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`.

As I understand it the `GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess` and the `GoogleSignInApi.signOut` both makes the user pick an account again.

But what more specifically is the differences in the above three?

Comment: in firebase you can authenticate a user of google,facebook,twitter or github. In you case it firebase varifies its a valid google user and creates a new user id in firabase corresponding to the google account you used for your app . When you call signout on googlesigninapi it logs out only user from google account. If you need to logout the firebase user you need to call signout on firebaseauth

Answer (score 2):

When you sign in, Google saves data connection in your Google account.
If you use sign out, you are just disconnected from your app.
If you use revokeaccess, you are disconnected from your app and data connection is deleted from your Google account (section Applications and web sites connected in your Google profile)

Answer (score 0):

There are different auth functionalities that you can provide to your app users.

All are working as a authentication. You can either choose any one of the techniques to authenticate user in your app.

Authentication with google plus requires `GoogleSignInApi.signOut`and `GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess`.

Whereas Firebase auth reuires `FirebaseAuth.signOut()`.

Comment: I get the picture a little thanks, to login to FirebaseAuth I must have a GoogleSignInApi Success

Comment: yes.. but when you are authenticate your user with google in firebase... For that once you sign in with google then you need to call mAuth.signInWithCredential in firebase to register google user in your app... Its similar as we are storing in our backend